# Custom activation email not working in Django

Tags: django, html-email

The goal is custom email with activation token. Currently, this setup works to click through to a url, but not with the activation link. The first template is the html content and the second is the message content.

```
from_email = '<info@domain>'
#this is the custom template
htmly = get_template('activation.html')
#this is just the template of the message
message = render_to_string('activation_email.html', {
                'user':user,
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
})
reverse(
'activate',
kwargs={
    'token':force_text(urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))),
    'uidb64':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
})
subject = 'Email activation'
html_content = htmly.render(d) 
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, [request.user.email])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

The error that I get is:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments
```

If I try to send it as one template, i.e. both the message and my custom html in the message. My html renders as a string.

This is the email that I'm trying to send. The activation_email has the message below and activation.html has the custom email html template.

activation_email.html

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Email confirmation:
http://domain{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

url.py

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

EDIT: The reverse below fixed this bug, but it still did not fix the url. You cannot click through.

This is the other email template if it helps.

```
<h3>Hi <strong>{{ username }}</strong>,</h3>
<p> Email Confirmation</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://domain{% url 'activate' uidb64=uidb64 token=token %}">Email Activation</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `reverse` with `uid` in `kwargs` but your URL is defined to expect `uidb64`

How about:

```
reverse(
    'activate',
    kwargs={
        'token':force_text(urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))),
        'uidb64':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
    })
```

Comment: thanks this fixes the problem of the reverse, but the link still doesn't show up.

Comment: You are passing `url` to HTML context. Use it in your activation template. {% if url %} {{ url }} {% endif %} etc.

Comment: Also, your templates are inconsistent. They are doing the same thing with different context. How about changing that?

Comment: Sorry changed after posted, my templates are consistent